# How to visualize the complex transformation $\exp(x+iy)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand the end result of the transformation. The imaginary axis wraps around the the unit circle and the left half is mapped inside the unit circle with the center at $-\infty$ and the right half mapped to outside the unit circle.

But how do I imagine the transformation happening?

I'll elaborate.

Suppose I my transformation is a complex number $re^{i\theta}$. This can be imagined as stretching and rotating the complex plane. Every instant of that stretching can be fed to a computer and animated.

For example: for k=1:r             z'=z*k

So that not only do I understand the plane I had at the beginning and the transformed plane but also every plane in between.

That's what I want with the transformation exp(x+iy). I want to be able to animate it. I guess a more coherent question would be how I can animate(mathematically speaking, with the relevant equations) the transformation exp(x+iy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trasformation of $z=x+iy \to e^{x+iy}$ maps the complex number $z=x+iy$ to the circle with radius $e^x=e^{\Re(z)}$ and argument $y$.

Then all points with $\Re(z)=k$ are mapped to the same circle ciclically for $2k\pi\le y \le 2(k+1)\pi$.

Then the "animation" coresponds to all vertical lines wrapped around circles with radius incresing from $0$ to $\infty$ as $\Re(z)$ goes from $-\infty$ to $-\infty$.

Comment: It is apparent from the question that OP is aware of this.

Comment: @amsmath Ah ok, my aim was give an intuition about the possible "animation" with all vertical lines wrapped around circles.

Comment: Is there any mathematical concept that deals with performing half of a transformation or infinitesimally small part of a transformation. Lets say by your rule, I start mapping vertical lines. Vertical line at -inf is mapped to a point. And so on until I get to the imaginary axis and I stop in between. Now I have a unit circle filled with concentric circles and the right half sitting as it is. 

Is there a way of thinking about this such that the whole plane is changing but not all at once, what mathematical equation would describe it in a transient state when it is not completely transformed

Comment: you could animate the lines moving, or you could take a sequence of functions approaching $e^z$ (e.g. Taylor Series convergent, limit of $(1+1/n)^n$, etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*. The following picture says a lot:

> [image]